# How to understand the transmission coefficient from the following question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

I want to understand the transmission coefficient and construct a time-independent Schrodinger equation where
$$
V(x)=\left\{
   \begin{array}{c c}
   \delta(x), & |x| < 1 \\
   + \infty, & |x| \geq 1.  \\
   \end{array}
  \right.
$$
$$
\Psi(x,0)=\left\{
   \begin{array}{c c}
   1, & 0< x < 1 \\
   0, & others.  \\
   \end{array}
  \right.
$$
I find out $\Psi(x,t)$ but it is too complict. And I find the transmission coefficient is zero since $\Psi(x,0)=0$ at $|x|=1$. In another hand, if $\Psi(x,t) \neq 0, (-1<x<0, t>0)$, there must be some 'probability' transimit to $x<0$. Thus, there will be a transimission coefficient.

> Can you help me check out $\Psi(x,t)$ and the transimission coefficient? Any help or suggestion about how to understand transimission coefficient from this dynamic process will be appreciated!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential#Solving_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation